# using bool without if and var expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript

What  string `console && (typeof console.log === "function") && console.log('contains called');` is doing in this function:

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.addMethod('contains', function (value, element, param) {
    console && (typeof console.log === "function") && console.log('contains called');
    if (this.optional(element)) { return true; } // let required rule deal with this.

    var pattern = new RegExp('' + param, "gi");
    return value && ('' + value).match(pattern);
}, "Part of the word is invalid");

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('contains', function (options) {
    var element = options.element,
            message = options.message;
    options.rules['contains'] = $(element).attr('data-val-contains-word');
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages['contains'] = options.message;
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

I would understand if that string was like:
`var var1 = console && (typeof console.log === "function") && console.log('contains called');`

or like: `if(console && (typeof console.log === "function") && console.log('contains called'))`

It's not a buggy code. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a less readable way of writing:

```
if (console && (typeof console.log === "function")) {
  console.log('contains called');
}
```

It (mis)uses the fact that you can write an expression that doesn't do anything with the result, and that a statement is also an expression, so it can be written inside an expression to do something.

Answer (score 1):

It just writes something to the browsers console.. But only if that console is available and if it has a 'log' function.
The first 2 conditions can prevent the third from running, thus not causing a js error in case console.log(..) does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime checks the first condition. If there isn't a console, it stops checking the other conditions because `false && ...` is in every case `false`. If there is a `console` the runtime checks if `console.log` is a function and if so it logs something to the console.
This is called [short-curcuit-evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Otherwise the runtime would always try to execute each condition which would lead to runtime errors if e.g. there were no console object.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing the same as

```
if (console && (typeof console.log === "function")) {
    console.log('contains called');
}
```

The interpreter will stop as soon as something is false so `console.log` won't be called if `console` doesn't have a `log` function. It won't check if this function exist neither if `console` doesn't even exist.